# div slide using javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

How can I move the div from right to left? Same as cycle rotation.

I having one HTML page in that 2 buttons called forward and backward.

When the user clicks forward button it `div` show move to next `div1`. The same as the backward button should move to the previous button.

Thanks and Regards

Ravi Kumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [jQuery UI Slide](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide)